# Return true if x is in list else False (Recursion)

Tags: list, haskell

I'm writing a short recursive function to take a list as input and output a Bool. (I'm haskell beginner) So far I can detect if the first element is a 3 or not, but I'm not sure how to use recursion to check the rest of the list.

```hs
func :: [Int] -> Bool
func [] = False
func (x:xs)
  | (x == 3)           = True
  | otherwise          = False
```

Comment: `otherwise = func xs`

Comment: You could consider writing your response (with a bit more explanation) as an answer if it is received well.

Answer (score 4):

I'm new to Haskell too.

by a little change to your code, it could be re-written as

```
func :: [Int] -> Bool
func [] = False
func (x:xs)
  | x == 3    = True
  | otherwise = func xs
```

explain:

- if list is empty: there is no 3
- if list is no empty:

  1. if head is 3, then we have 3
  2. otherwise we should check rest of the list, so answer of "3 is in list" is equivalent to " x is in xs".

if you accept a little change, i can suggest implementing with OR (and help of lazy evaluation).

```hs
func :: [Int] -> Bool
func [] = False
func (x:xs) = x==3 || func xs
```

it is really same as the upper code, but with less lines.

- if head is 3, return True.
- if head is not 3, check rest of list.

at last, I want to introduce you `elem` function, it works as: get an element and a list, return True if a is in list, otherwise False.
It is exactly what we want here, so i write:

```hs
containsThree :: [Int] -> Bool
containsThree = elem 3
```

also note that I used point-free style, if you are not familiar, second line is same as:

```hs
containsThree xs = elem 3 xs
```

Good luck learning Haskell.

Comment: I would note that `elem` is typically written as an infix operator, ``3 `elem` xs``, which kind of reads more understandable, like the maths notation 3 ∈ _xs_.